# Regular Expression {POST:name}

Tags: php, regex, forms, input, preg-match-all

I know a bit about Regular Expression but really want to learn more about it and now i'm trying to make a function that detects all {} in my content (from a database) and checks what between the brackets. If there is a POST or GET with a name (format: POST:name or GET:name} i would like to replace them with that value.

Example:
When i have a form with the following inputs:

```
Name
Email
Message
```

And then in the value attribute i type: `{POST:Name}` 
Then the script must detect the `{POST:Name}` and will replace it with the string in `$_POST['name']`. I already searched on Google, but found too much that i don't know what to really use.

Now i have:

```
<?php
        preg_match_all("/{(POST|GET):[.*](})/", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

        foreach($matches AS $match)
        {
            if(isset($_POST[$match]))
                $content = str_replace('{POST:'.$match, $_POST[$match], $content);
            else
                $content = str_replace('{GET:'.$match, $_GET[$match], $content);
        }

?>
```

But this don't work.

Comment: Only the content is from a database.

Comment: Is that is templating code inside the database? You better should create a template engine then. Also a template *does not need to know whether that is POST or GET or WHATEVAR* (which then will even make the replacement more easy for you).

Comment: This is just a snippet of the whole script, this is for after the post has been done by a user to get the filled in data back in the form.

Comment: You want a regex like `~{(POST|GET):([^}]+)}~`. Then look at the `$matches` array. That being said, this looks like a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly i was searching for. Thanks! And what is your opinion about a good way then?

Comment: @Wouter0100 I am not exactly sure of what you're trying to accomplish, but this is a very uncommon request, which leads me to believe you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use preg_replace, better than str_replace.
And if you use preg_replace, you don't need no more your first condition, et can do the same code with only one instruction.

https://www.php.net/preg_replace

```
<?php preg_replace('#{(POST|GET):(.*)}#','$_$1[$2]',$content); ?>
```

My regex can be false, but something like this should work.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'.

Comment: <?php preg_replace('#{(POST|GET):(.*)}#','$_$1[$2]',$content); ?>

Comment: Added callback to it, now it works. Thanks both! @above i think still same error because you cant use $1 (first char can't be a number in a var)

Comment: It's because I'm stupid and tired.
The second argument of preg_replace isn't php varibale, it's a string.

Comment: @Wouter0100 This regex will blow up if the input contains more than one brace, eg: `My name is {POST:name}, I like {POST:food}`

Comment: I know, thats the reason i start using preg_replace_callback. It works fine now.